# QGIS Referencer: Tranformed Failed

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm using a new install of QGIS 2.18.2 on an iMac running OSX 10.10.5.

I create a new project.  I use the OpenLayers plugin to show an OSM background of a part of Mayfair in London.  I now use the Georeferencer to add an 9Mb .png (copy of a web map) and import three points. All the SRS/CRS are set to EPSG:3857. Transformation settings are linear.

[This Dropbox folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cazhx5j2amz55lh/AACpWfnsS5qS-UBV8vqikwWpa?dl=0) contains a copy of

- the 9Mb map I'm trying to transform
- the points I have previously saved
- a screen copy of the transformation settings
- a screen copy of the QGIS window showing the GCP table and the two maps

At this point I run the transform and I get the message:
Transform failed: Failed to compute GCP transform: Transform is not solvable.

I have no idea of what is going wrong here.  I have managed to use exactly the same process (with a different but very similar .png) and it has worked, but an attempt to add a second file usually seems to fail.   Trying to add the map that did work to this project also failed in the same way.  Many other images/points have failed as well.   I've also reduced the PNG to a 1.6Mb jpg and this also fails in the same way.